# How To Remove Navigation Controller Back Button Text

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

When you create a navigation controller in the storyboard and create a segue to another view controller you automatically get this back button with an arrow and the title of previous page. (see image)

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSYTy.jpg)

How can I delete the text and still have the arrow there? 
or
How can I replace with my own image?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to replace the arrow with your own image, thats the way I've always done it anyway

Answer (score 6):

Inside your `viewDidLoad` of the setting you can use this to change the title

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem()
backButton.title = "" //in your case it will be empty or you can put the title of your choice
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

and this to set your own image

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "backButton")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement UINavigationControllerDelegate like this:

```
 func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
    }
```

it affects next pushed controller `backBarButtonItem`title.

**edit:**
in your `ViewController`

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. Don't know what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: @DanielSandberg edited answer check.

Comment: Great solution.